# Matching subdirectory by comparing part of the directory path

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I probably didn't word the title too well but hopefully my explanation should illustrate the problem.

Basically, I have to find out the names of the subdirectories excluding the file name when given another path to compare with. For instance,

```
Given: "C:\Windows\System32\catroot\sys.dll"

Compare: "C:\Windows"

Matched String: "\System32\catroot"
```

Here's another example:

```
Given: "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Examples\profile.ps1"

Compare: "C:\Windows\System32"

Matched String: "\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Examples"
```

What would be the best way to perform this matching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might also want to consider special cases such as:

- Relative paths
- Paths with short names such as `C:\PROGRA~1` for `C:\Program Files`
- Non-canonical paths (`C:\Windows\System32\..\..\file.dat`)
- Paths that use an alternate separator (`/` instead of `\`)

One way is to convert to a canonical full path using `Path.GetFullPath` before comparing

E.g.

```
string toMatch = @"C:\PROGRA~1/";
string path1 = @"C:/Program Files\Common Files\..\file.dat";
string path2 = @"C:\Program Files\Common Files\..\..\file.dat";

string toMatchFullPath = Path.GetFullPath(toMatch);
string fullPath1 = Path.GetFullPath(path1);
string fullPath2 = Path.GetFullPath(path2);

// fullPath1 = C:\Program Files\file.dat
// toMatchFullPath = C:\Program Files\
if (fullPath1.StartsWith(toMatchFullPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    // path1 matches after conversion to full path
}

// fullPath2 = C:\file.dat
// toMatchFullPath = C:\Program Files\
if (fullPath2.StartsWith(toMatchFullPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    // path2 does not match after conversion to full path
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use Regex.
This could be easily done using [string.StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452.aspx), [string.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6) and [Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) to remove the filename.

```
string fullPath = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Examples\profile.ps1"; 
string toMatch = @"C:\Windows\System32";
string result = string.Empty;
if(fullPath.StartsWith(toMatch, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == true)
{
    result = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath.Substring(toMatch.Length));
} 
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

EDIT: this changes take care of the observation from aiodintsov and include the idea from @Joe about non-canonical or partial path names

```
string fullPath = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Examples\profile.ps1"; 
string toMatch = @"C:\Win";

string result = string.Empty;
string temp = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetFullPath(fullPath));
string[] p1 = temp.Split('\\');
string[] p2 = Path.GetFullPath(toMatch).Split('\\');
for(int x = 0; x < p1.Length; x++)
{
   if(x >= p2.Length || p1[x] != p2[x]) 
             result = string.Concat(result, "\\", p1[x]);
}
```

In this case I assume that the partial match should be considered as no match.
Also take a look at the answer from @Joe for the problem of partial or non-canonical paths

Comment: Does this remove the file name at end? From the looks of it, it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: Sorry you are right, missed that part of the question. I have updated the answer

Comment: Good, but not good enough ))) imagine toMatch=@"c:\Win" )
There are possible ways to improve

Comment: But this means that the two strings are arbitrary given or coming from two different PCs. Sorry but I was assuming that these were real paths on the same machine. Hope that OP explains this aspect of its question

Comment: @aiodintsov, I have added another version that take care of the partial match problem you have suggested